# Flutter: reduce switch toggle size and reduce freed space to the left without stack

Tags: flutter, switch-statement, label, size

So I have already learned here from studying the questions that I have to

- transform.scale the switch (instead of wrapping a smaller container)
- offset the scaling origin by a point size in order to keep the switch right aligned, since the layout space remains untouched (switch still requesting the non-scaled size)

Is there a better solution than creating a stack to have the switch label near to the switch?

Background: I have Column([Row(Text(), Switch()) , Row(Text(), Switch())]) in which the switch needs to be right aligned to the column border and the text needs to fill the remaining space due to space restrictions. Currently there is a significant gap between text and switch due to the 100% layout space request of the switch.